# get result from select avg

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the result of SQL AVG.

```
console.log(results[0]) show me this:
RowDataPacket { 'AVG(rapportqualiteprix)': 1.333333 }
```

but when I want to get the value with this javascript command, I get an error like this is not a function.

my command:

```
results[0].AVG(rapportqualiteprix)
```

help

Comment: This does not appear to be plain JavaScript or Node.js. Please add a tag for whatever additional technology you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AVG(rapportqualiteprix)** is a key, not a `function`. It was a `function` when your query ran, but it is an item key in your Javascript. You can get its value this way:

```
results[0]['AVG(rapportqualiteprix)']
```